# how to $.post() specific element value using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to post hidden values using jquery, I have more than 2 groups of `h2` tags which have 5 childrens `2 span` `2 input hidden` `1 input button` and I fetch the values of spans into the hidden values and thats working fine, and after I am trying to `$.post()` values of input hidden using jquery but that is not working correct.

this is the structure.

```
<h2 style="color:green;">Domain <span class="domain">domain.org</span> is available.
<span class="domain_price">$9.95/year</span> 
<input type="hidden" class="order_domain" name="order_domain" value="$9.95/year">
<input type="hidden" class="domain_name" name="domain" value="domain.org">
<input type="button" class="button3" value="Order Now">
</h2>

<h2 style="color:green;">Domain <span class="domain">domain.biz</span> is available.
<span class="domain_price">$9.95/year</span> 
<input type="hidden" class="order_domain" name="order_domain" value="$9.95/year">
<input type="hidden" class="domain_name" name="domain" value="domain.biz">
<input type="button" class="button3" value="Order Now">
</h2>

<h2 style="color:green;">Domain <span class="domain">domain.net</span> is available.
<span class="domain_price">$9.95/year</span> 
<input type="hidden" class="order_domain" name="order_domain" value="$9.95/year">
<input type="hidden" class="domain_name" name="domain" value="domain.net">
<input type="button" class="button3" value="Order Now">
</h2>
```

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('input[type="button"]').on('click', function() {
        domain_price = $(this).parents('h2').children('.domain_price').text();
        $(this).siblings('.order_domain').val(domain_price);
        order_domain = $('.order_domain').val();

        domain = $(this).parents('h2').children('.domain').text();
        $(this).siblings('.domain_name').val(domain);
        domain_name = $('.domain_name').val();
        //setTimeout(function(){
        $.post('orderdomain.php',{order_domain:order_domain, domain:domain_name},function(data){
        //});
        },1000);
    });
});
```

the problem is when I click the button to post the values from any other groups from first group, they posted empty values into the db.
and when I click the button from first group of `h2` its posted correctly ito the db.

so why only the posted successfully into db from first group of `h2`?

why not working others if they posted first?

**updated**

its looks like

```
$form = '<input type="hidden" class="order_domain" name="order_domain">
        <input type="hidden" class="domain_name" name="domain">
        <input type="button" class="button3" value="Order Now">';
            switch($tld) {
                case '.com':
                    $msg .= "<h2 style='color:green;' >Domain <span class='domain'>$domain</span> is available. <span class='domain_price'>".$prices['.com']."/year</span> ".$form."</h2>";
        break;
    ....
```

Comment: Are all the `input(s)` included in the same form?

Comment: Why are you filling hidden inputs if you are not using them / posting via AJAX? `order_domain = $('.order_domain').val();` will select the first occurence of `.order_domain` on the page.

Comment: no, they don't have form yet, but they have before now.

I realized that they don't need if I am using $.post to post them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you select the correct values, then set the adjacent input fields to those values - this works fine.

Then you inexplicably try and reselect the values out of the input fields (incorrectly). This is all unnecessary as you select the correct values in the 1st place, simply use those values in your ajax data:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('input[type="button"]').on('click', function() {
        domain_price = $(this).parents('h2').children('.domain_price').text();
        $(this).siblings('.order_domain').val(domain_price);
        //order_domain = $('.order_domain').val(); <-your error    
        domain = $(this).parents('h2').children('.domain').text();
        $(this).siblings('.domain_name').val(domain);
        //domain_name = $('.domain_name').val(); <- your error
        //setTimeout(function(){
        $.post('orderdomain.php',{order_domain:domain_price, domain:domain},function(data){
        //});
        },1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: What I have tried is works fine and posted into the db, the problem is that whenever i post from any of the other first group of h2 they posted empty in the db, not the first group.

Comment: @hsn0331 Yes, i understad that - I highlighted your problem in my answer. Did you actually try my solution

Answer (score 0):

It is pointless to fill a `hidden` `input` with a value and get that value to post it via AJAX.
Just get the `.text()` straight away and post that. It is the same anyway.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('input[type="button"]').on('click', function () {
        order_domain = $(this).parents('h2').children('.domain_price').text();
        domain_name = $(this).parents('h2').children('.domain').text();
        $.post('orderdomain.php', {
            order_domain: order_domain,
            domain: domain_name
        }, function (data) {
            // do something
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: and this groups is generated by php, not a static html.

Comment: Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('input[type="button"]').on('click', function() {
    domain_price = $(this).parents('h2').children('.domain_price').text();
    $(this).siblings('.order_domain').val(domain_price);
    order_domain = $('.order_domain').val();// this always get the input value of the first group, so just use domain_price

    domain = $(this).parents('h2').children('.domain').text();
    $(this).siblings('.domain_name').val(domain);
    domain_name = $('.domain_name').val();// same as before

    $.post('orderdomain.php',{order_domain:order_domain, domain:domain_name},function(data){
});
```

});

Comment: this is the example of this, http://jsfiddle.net/L89421js/ @dencey

only the difference is it has not $.post function yet.